# Do lambdas get executed in the context of the calling script or the context of the defined script?

Tags: python

If the following function is defined in a different file and returned and executed in a separate file, will it give the file name of where it was defined? Or where it was called?

```
File1.py
-----
def get_current_filename():
        return lambda: os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(__file__))

File2.py
----
import File1
x= File1.get_current_filename()
x()
```

Comment: You could try this yourself by changing the lambda body to `print(__file__)`

Comment: this isn't to do with `lambda` directly, a regular `def` function would behave the same

Comment: You're essentially asking if Python is dynamically scoped or statically scoped language (it's the latter). Using a lambda is a irrelevant here, it's not like a lisp lambda.

Comment: `lambda` is irrelevant, Python uses lexical scoping, and does not support dynamic scoping. Maybe a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture ?

Comment: I don't think it's irrelevant in some languages being that the Lambda is passed to the calling script and executed in the context of the calling script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will use the filename where it was defined, i.e. `File1.py`.

The import system populates the `__file__` attribute on each module object during module loading. Docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes).

Note that there is no supported way to get the calling module's filename (`File2.py`) here, that's only possible with hacks. Avoid.

Comment: Haha was literally typing up how to get the name with the calling file when your edi popped up. Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 2):

As wim said, the function gets executed in such a way that `__file__` will return the name of the file the function is present in (File1.py).

It is however possible to achieve what you want, although again as wim said it is a bit hacky. You can do this by looking at the frame records in the call stack using [`inspect.stack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack):

File1.py:

```
import inspect

def get_current_filename():
        return inspect.stack()[1][1]
```

File2.py:

```
import File1
x = File1.get_current_filename()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
C:\<omitted>\File2.py
```

The first `[1]` indicates to look at the second frame in the call stack (the first frame being the location that called `inspect.stack`, the second being the location that called that), the second `[1]` gets the filename from the frame.

Comment: That is fascinating. Thanks for adding this!  Using it!